# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from `posts`)

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Getting this error in laravel when I try to get data from database `(Post::all())`. Migration works well​ it creates table columns but this isn't working.

Comment: is it correct .env files ?

Comment: Yes, That's why migration is working.

Comment: change `DB_HOST` from `127.0.0.1` to `localhost`

Comment: Try `dd($_SERVER)` and confirm that your environement variables are all in there. Make sure that your run that command in the same environment as where the issue is e.g. if the issue happens on web requests try running that within a web request to confirm that your .env settings are correctly exported

Comment: show your `.env` settings

Comment: Solved by restarting the server `php artisan serve`. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you have done any changes in .env file,You have to restart the server using 'php artisan serve' command.Otherwise the changes won't reflects.

Answer (score 0):

Youu must use these template default variables. For mysql

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=yourdatabasename
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=null
```

Comment: tried this, not working.
I have added `DB_SOCKET=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock` in .env file and now i am getting this error `SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from 'posts')`. I don't know from where it is getting homestead user.

Comment: these are laravel defaults. but you need create your own database. after that these information update. did you work for you?

Comment: if you do php artisan migrate and it works your env variables are alright, however Access denied for user leads me to believe that you have the incorrect credentials to access your DB.

Comment: Solved by restarting the server `php artisan serve`. Thanks